# How to set up scheduled backups in amazon s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, database-backups, s3cmd

I have S3 bucket "foo.backups", s3cmd is installed on my DigitalOcean droplet. I need to backup mydb.sqlite3 database and "myfolder".

How to make scheduled daily backups of these databse and folder with such structure:

```
s3://foo.backups/
-30jan15/
--mydb.sqlite3
--myfolder/
---...
-31jan15/
--mydb.sqlite3
--myfolder/
---...
-1feb15/
--mydb.sqlite3
--myfolder/
---...
```

How can I set it up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `s3cmd`, `aws-cli` - you might consider using https://github.com/minio/mc

`mc` implements `mc mirror` command to recursively sync files and directories to multiple destinations in parallel.

Features a cool progress bar and session management for resumable copy/mirror operations.

```
$ mc mirror
NAME:
   mc mirror - Mirror folders recursively from a single source to many destinations.

USAGE:
   mc mirror SOURCE TARGET [TARGET...]

EXAMPLES:
   1. Mirror a bucket recursively from Minio cloud storage to a bucket on Amazon S3 cloud storage.
      $ mc mirror https://play.minio.io:9000/photos/2014 https://s3.amazonaws.com/backup-photos

   2. Mirror a local folder recursively to Minio cloud storage and Amazon S3 cloud storage.
      $ mc mirror backup/ https://play.minio.io:9000/archive https://s3.amazonaws.com/archive

   3. Mirror a bucket from aliased Amazon S3 cloud storage to multiple folders on Windows.
      $ mc mirror s3/documents/2014/ C:\backup\2014 C:\shared\volume\backup\2014

   4. Mirror a local folder of non english character recursively to Amazon s3 cloud storage and Minio cloud storage.
      $ mc mirror 本語/ s3/mylocaldocuments play/backup

   5. Mirror a local folder with space characters to Amazon s3 cloud storage
      $ mc mirror 'workdir/documents/Aug 2015' s3/miniocloud
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `s3cmd`, you might consider using the [AWS Command-Line Interface](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) (CLI).

The CLI has an `aws s3 sync` command that will copy directories and sub-directories to/from Amazon S3. You can also nominate which filetypes are included/excluded. It will only copies that a new or have been modified since the previous sync.

See: [AWS CLI S3 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)